# How can I izip in python with sorted output?

Tags: sorting, iterator, python, yield

For lack of a better name, I'd like to do an "izip_sorted" in Python.  The input to the function is a number of iterables, each sorted.  The ouput is a single iterable with sorted output.

```
print([x for x in izip_sorted([0,4,8], [1,3,5], [12,12,42],[])])
```

**Edit:** This is a simple example.  The real usage will be on about 40 input iterables, each with about 100000 elements.  Each element is a class stores a dict and implements `__cmp__` so that the elements can be sorted.  The data is too large to read in all at once.

should print

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 12, 12, 42]
```

I have a solution but I'm new to python and I don't know that it's very *Pythonic*.  Can this be improved upon?  The sort where only 1 element has changed seems wasteful...

```
def izip_sorted(*iterables):
    """
    Return an iterator that outputs the values from the iterables, in sort order
    izip_sort('ABF', 'D', 'CE') --> A B C D E F
    """
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    current_iterators = []
    for it in iterators:
        try:
            current_iterators.append((next(it), it))
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    current_iterators.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    while(current_iterators):
        yield current_iterators[0][0]
        try:
            current_iterators[0] = (next(current_iterators[0][1]), current_iterators[0][1])
            current_iterators.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
        except StopIteration:
            current_iterators = current_iterators[1:]
```

Comment: This is a really misleading name, as it doesn't really have anything to do with the `izip()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the inputs are not sorted, then they must all be realized (essentially, turned from an iterable into a list).  You can't sort without looking at the data.  [LattyWare's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10666382/25050) is the most pythonic.

If on the other hand, the input iterables are known to be sorted, you can use [heapq.merge](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge):

```
>>> from heapq import merge
>>> merge(*iterables)
```

Comment: In my defense, the code for heapq.merge is not much different from mine, though merge() uses a heap for sorting which is faster when just 1 element might be wrong (as I'd suspected).  I wasn't completely off!

Comment: Too bad it doesn't support a custom key function.

Comment: @AlexB: not supporting a custom key function is not really a big deal; just use the old decorate-sort-undecorate pattern, which can be done without losing laziness.

Comment: @LieRyan I ended up simply emitting tuples from the iterables, with the first item being the key I need to sort on.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is to chain all the values of the iterables, and then sort them. To do this, we can simply combine [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [the `sorted()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sorted(chain([0,4,8], [1,3,5], [12,12,42],[]))
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 12, 12, 42]
```

If you had a list of iterables, you would want to use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
>>> iterables = [[0,4,8], [1,3,5], [12,12,42],[]]
>>> sorted(chain.from_iterable(iterables))
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 12, 12, 42]
```

Edit: For your exact problem, given you know that the input lists are sorted, and that the last item of each input list will be no bigger than the first of the next list, we simply sort based on the first value (using `sorted()`'s key function) then chain them.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> iterables = [[0,4,8], [1,3,5], [12,12,42]]
>>> sorted(iterables, key=itemgetter(0))
[[0, 4, 8], [1, 3, 5], [12, 12, 42]]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(sorted(iterables, key=itemgetter(0))))
[0, 4, 8, 1, 3, 5, 12, 12, 42]
```

The problem is, the data you have given us doesn't follow these rules, hence the incorrect answer.

Comment: There's no need to construct a brand new list with a call to list()

Comment: @MrFooz That was purely for the example, so that you could see the results. Edit: Derp, `sorted()`, of course, returns a list. Editing. I've become over-zealous with wrapping examples with `list()` to show the output. My mistake.

Comment: I edited the question.  My sample code was using small lists but the real code is trying to sort 40 iterables, each about 100000 elements, each element a dict with about 20 items.  It doesn't fit in memory, that's why I'm using iterables in the first place!

Comment: @Eyal As I said before, `itertools.chain()` is a generator, and hence lazy - it will only deal with one item at a time. That said, `sorted()` isn't, but to sort your values, you need to have them available. There is no way to lazily sort something, as you have to know the other values to know where any one value should place.

Comment: @Lattyware That's why I specified that each iterable **is** sorted.  It's sufficient to look at the first element of each iterable.

Answer (score 2):

This is not `zip`. `zip` zips several iterables into an iterable yielding tuples. Your function is simply:

```
sorted(itertools.chain(*iterables))
```

Comment: If you were to suggest using `*iterables` you'd be better off using `chain.from_iterable()`.

Comment: I edited the question.  I'm not using chain because in reality the lists are very long, there are many of them, and the elements of the lists are big.  In fact, just reading the elements into memory grinds my computer to a halt.

Comment: @Eyal `itertools.chain()` is a generator - it will only deal with one item at a time.

Comment: @Lattyware So how will it work?  If the smallest item is in the last iterator, won't it need to first get all the items from the previous iterators and store them somewhere before outputting the last one?  I don't see how it's possible to sort the output of chain without first putting all the output of chain into memory.

Comment: @Eyal I've basically responded to that on my question, I don't want to duplicate the discussion across two questions, so look there.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do:

```
sorted([item for iterable in iterables for item in iterable])
```

Comment: True, but the list comprehension solution is less efficient than `itertools.chain()`, and less readable.